# Pandas: Compute average of a column by count of another column, without grouping by

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Is there a pandas function to do something like (sum(A)/count(distinct B)), where A, and B are columns in a dataframe. A has continuous values whereas B has categorical values. The dataframe may have other columns in addition.I don't want to group by, just get the weighted average.

Example: Average orders across users would be sum(orders)/count(distinct user_id) where orders and user ids would be columns in the dataframe.

Sample dataframe:

```
        OrderQuantity CustomerID
0             10       1214
1              9       1214
2              8       1213
3             14       1213
4             3        1213
```

What I need is something like `sum(df['OrderQuantity'])/len(df['CustomerID'].unique())` i.e `44/2 = 22` in this case but I was wondering if there was way to do it with pandas, so the result would be a dataframe with a column named `OrderQuantity` and a single row holding the value.

Comment: can you provide a minimal example? why no `groupby`?

Comment: I don't need the average per group. Just the weighted average. I'll add an example.

Comment: No, not a single function, but something you can do with a couple of "pre" calculations then compute the final calculation as you mentioned here.  If you provide data and an expected output, we can show you how we'd do it.

Comment: I think the question is still unclear, please provide a **minimal** example (just a few rows, no "...", enough to explain how the logic works) and the matching expected output

Answer (score 0):

Your formula has two members, so the problem is solved in two steps with pd.Series in the end.

```
n = df.CustomerID.nunique()
df.drop(columns='CustomerID').sum() / n
```

You also want a table of one row with the same column labels - just transpose the output. This one-liner solves the problem:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.drop(columns='CustomerID').sum() / df.CustomerID.nunique()).T
```

Comment: But this wouldn't work when the dataframe has more columns. I need a solution that'd work regardless of other columns in the df.

Comment: Eg: If there's a third column say, year, the output would have to be grouped by year.

Comment: Requirement "Group by year" was not set initially. So it is an additional operation. As to current question formulation (summing of some number columns), this decision works.

Answer (score -1):

df['OrderQuantity'].sum()/df['CustomerID'].drop_duplicates().count()

Comment: I've already mentioned this in the question. This doesnt scale when the dataframes have other columns.